# Redirect to a locale based on cookie

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

Our site uses custom locales. We save the locale a user selects in a cookie. How would I add to my htaccess file to accomplish redirecting to the proper locale based on the cookie? Our locales end up pre-pending `/dallas, /fort-worth , /plano` to the urls.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you set cookie locale=value
Then write .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} locale=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

i.e. www.examle.com/smtng.html => www.examle.com/value/index.php?p=smtng.html